# Custom route for dialogflow webhook

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have created a **dialogflow** with **webhook**. I have put all my webhook code inside a default **POST** route. Then I go to [webhook](https://dialogflow.cloud.google.com/) -> Integration and tested, It is working fine but What should I do to use a custom name for route. How it will be called ? Now it is default route so I haven't called that any where. It is automatically invoked when I test it with dialogflow chat window.

**Code**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const df = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
var voice =  "female";
var variant = "2"

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('We are live')
});


app.post('/', express.json(), (req, res) => {
    const agent = new df.WebhookClient({
        request: req,
        response: res
    });

    function getTime(agent) {
        let conv = agent.conv();
        var breakfastTime = agent.context.get('time');
            const ssml = '<speak> <voice language="fr-FR" gender="'+voice+'" variant="'+variant+'">' +
                'Thank you, Have a great day ' +
                ' </voice> </speak>';
            conv.ask(ssml);
            agent.add(conv);
        }

    var intentMap = new Map();
    intentMap.set('Time', getTime);

})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Sever is live"));
```

If I name the POST route `app.post('/firstHit', express.json(), (req, res) => {` how will I call this ?

Comment: To sum up, you want to change default route name to custom name? You don't want to create many routes but just rename default? Have you seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61056804/dialogflow-how-do-you-handle-a-nodejs-server-with-multiple-routes)?

Comment: Also Id like to confirm, you want to change the `POST` route name?